# How do I do table alignment?

Tags: tables

I have the following code:

```
\section{Database Design}

\begin{center}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{ | l |  l |}
    \hline
    Field & Type \\ \hline
    id & Primary key \\ \hline
    firstName & String \\ \hline
    lastName & String \\ \hline
    email & String \\ \hline
    password & String \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{User}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

There are a few alignment problems:

1. The table seems to be floating top left above my section
2. My caption is centered and out of line with the table

How can I center my table and have it placed below my 'Database Design' section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `\centering` inside `table` environment to center the table. Also the placement options `[htbp]` can be used to influence the placement of the table. An exclamation `!` like `[!h]` will force latex to place `h`ere.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Database Design} 
%    
\begin{table}[!h] %%,---- note the placement option
\centering    %%,------command here for centering
    \begin{tabular}{ | l |  l |}
    \hline
    Field & Type \\ \hline
    id & Primary key \\ \hline
    firstName & String \\ \hline
    lastName & String \\ \hline
    email & String \\ \hline
    password & String \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{User}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Also avoid using `\begin{center}.....\end{center}` as it will add extra vertical space (that may be unwanted in some cases like this). Instead use `\centering`.

For a more stricter placement pl. consult `float` package that provides an option `H` means *definitely here* (as opposed to `h` meaning *here if possible*). For more details consult the documentation of `float` (texdoc float) page no. 4.

[image]